# Restler class with required params based on method type

Tags: restler

Let's say I have this to use with my API classes

```php
class EventInfo {
    /// @var int $start The Start time
    public $start

    /// @var string $url The URL for the event {@required false}
    public $url = null;
}
```

And now I want to use `EventInfo` for both my POST and my PATCH methods.  When I'm doing a POST, `$start` is a required property to be set.  The `$url` will come in as an optional parameter.

However, when I'm doing a PATCH operation, then `$start` should no longer be required.  I might be passing a new start time, but I might not.

How do I specify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the **DocBlock** syntax

```
class EventInfo {
    /**
     * @var int $start The Start time
     */
    public $start;

    /**
     * @var string $url The URL for the event {@required false}
     */
    public $url = null;
}
```

This sets the default required and optional properties. Then you can control the required properties at api method level using `{@required }` comment. See the example below

```
class Home
{
    public function index()
    {
        return array(
            'success' => array(
                'code' => 200,
                'message' => 'Restler is up and running!',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function patch(EventInfo $info)
    {
        return func_get_args();
    }

    /**
     * @param EventInfo $info {@required start,url}
     * @return array
     */
    public function post(EventInfo $info)
    {
        return func_get_args();
    }
}
```

You may also add `{@properties start}` comment similarly to restrict which properties are needed by the API method.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as I already have that. $start is going to always be required with what you showed.

Comment: How do I *add* to the required properties, not just replace them?  If my class has 10 properties, and 8 of them are required true, and now I want my method to also make the other two required, it appears that I would have to list all 10 of them on the `@param EventInfo` line.  I'd like to be able to just list the two that are normally not required and have all 10 be required.

Comment: Once you override, you have to provide the full list. This is the only way to have complete control